# Selecting inserted record in Oracle from PHP OCI

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oracle-call-interface

I am executing a PLSQL Block using OCI from my PHP site which is running some procedures inside. The final procedure is returning the inserted records rowid of a specific table.

```
BEGIN

  proc1(1);
  proc2(2, rowid_);

END;
```

What I want to do is, I want to get the primary key values of the record for this rowid?

Is there a way to run it somehow like below and get the select results out to PHP with oci_fetch_row or something?

```
BEGIN

  proc1();
  proc2(rowid_); -- out variable

 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM my_table
 WHERE rowid = rowid_;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way. Try something like:

```
DECLARE
  nPK_col  NUMBER;
  nCol1    NUMBER := 1;
  nCol2    NUMBER := 2;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(COL1, COL2)
    VALUES (nCol1, nCol2)
    RETURNING PK_COL INTO nPK_col;
END;
```

This example assumes that the primary key column named `PK_COL` is populated in some way during the execution of the `INSERT` statement, e.g. by a trigger. The `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement specifies that the value of `PK_COL` from the inserted row should be put into the variable specified, in this case `nPK_col`. You can specify multiple columns and variables in the `RETURNING` clause - [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF54954). You may need to put this into whatever procedure performs the actual `INSERT` and then add an `OUT` parameter to allow the value to be passed back to the caller - or use a `FUNCTION` instead of a `PROCEDURE` and have the primary key value be the return value of the `FUNCTION`.

Share and enjoy.